# Access non static control in web method asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I Want to access non static control in static web method

Below is my code,but I'm getting error while binding gridview with datatable object(dt),error is "Object Reference not set to an instance of object"
and the issue is my gridview control is showing null I.E its not acessible in web method

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static DataTable GetProductByID(string args)
    {

        string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlDataAdapter sda;
            DataTable dt;
            conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, BRANDNAME FROM TBLTBRAND WHERE ID = @productid";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brandname", data[1]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid", Convert.ToInt32(data[0]));
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            Default obcD = new Default();
            obcD.LoadData();

            return dt;

            **GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView; // error oocupy**
            **GridView1.DataBind();**

            sda.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: any server control is not available in any webmethods. do a regular postback rather than using webmethod

Comment: Actually i can't afford postback to occur,i just want to bind gridview with datatable ,i had tried binding gridview by calling another method with datatable as parameter from web method but gridview is showing null in that another method,what to do ??

Comment: as I said, you CAN'T use any server controls on a webmethod. that includes gridview, label, listview, etc. if you want to bind your data into your gridview using webmethod, do it client-side using javascript.